# XDMP-BADCHAR : Unexpected character found '\"'

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I tried to launch the following Xquery query via the API (I followed the link : https://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/REST/POST/v1/eval).

It works with the basic example, but when I try with a query to extract data from ML and save them to the disk, I have the following error:

```
{"errorResponse":{"statusCode":500, "status":"Internal Server Error", "messageCode":"XDMP-BADCHAR", "message":"XDMP-BADCHAR: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected character found '\"' (0x0022)", "messageDetail":{"messageTitle":"Unexpected character found"}}}
```

My xquery file contains :

```
xquery=
xquery version "1.0-ml";
xdmp:save("toto.csv",let $nl := "&#10;" return document { for $book in collection("book")/optIns where root($book)/duplicate eq false() return (root($book)/contactId||","|| root($book)/countryCode||$optin/updatedDate||$nl)})
```

Thanks,
Romain.

Comment: In your file, I don't see where you are specifying the content database.  It may also be helpful to see the curl command that you are using to execute the script.

Comment: Hi, you a re right ! I specifiy it in the curl command with "?database=XYZ"

Answer (score 3):

You probably have something in your query text that needs to be URL encoded. Try using `--data-urlencode` instead of `-d`, or otherwise URL-encode your form values before passing them to curl.